# How to return all names with second letter "h" - from an array of names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, indexof

I have to write a function that returns all users with a second letter of "h" in their name.

```
var users = ["Roman","Sherry","Sandrah","Shamaika"];
```

I started to code something like this but it is not working.

```
function letter(){
    var index = users.indexOf("h") == [1];
    return(index);
}
```

I am new to JavaScript and I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Try `users.filter((user) => user.chatAt(1) === 'h')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const users = ["Roman","Sherry","Sandrah","Shamaika"];

let filteredUsers = users.filter(user => user.charAt(1) === 'h');
console.log(filteredUsers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the array by taking a function which check the character at index `1`.

```js
function checkLetter1(string) {
    return string[1] === 'h';
}

var users = ["Roman", "Sherry", "Sandrah", "Shamaika"];

console.log(users.filter(checkLetter1));
```

Comment: You are wasted for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var users = ["Roman","Sherry","Sandrah","Shamaika"];

var index = users.filter(a=> a.indexOf("h") === 1);
console.log(index);
```

Comment: Why 1 as array?

Comment: @quirimmo sorry copied that from question, corrected now

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is looking for the first index of `h` in the array of user names, which will return incorrect results. Consider using the `Array#filter` method to select names that match your criteria of the second character being `h` like so:

```js
var users = ["Roman","Sherry","Sandrah","Shamaika"];

function letter(name){
    // Return true if the second character of name is an 'h'
    return name[1] === 'h';
}

// Use filter() method to get array of items that satisfy
// the criteria of your letter() function
var filteredUsers = users.filter(letter);

console.log(filteredUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like so:

```
function usersWithSecondH(users) {
  return users.filter(user => user[1] === 'h');
}
```

So essentially checking the value of the second letter and returning those names in a new array if it matches 'h';

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = ["Roman","Sherry","Sandrah","Shamaika"];
var t=users.filter((x)=>x.indexOf('h')==1)
console.log(t);
```

This will do

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return the array elements (as a result array) which have the second character as a "h":

```
var users = ["Roman", "Sherry", "Sandrah", "Shamaika"];

function getMyUsers() {
    return users.map(user => user.split(""))
                .filter(userChars => userChars[1] == "h")
                .map(userChars => user.join(""));
};

console.log(getMyUsers());
```

The Output:

```
[ "Sherry", "Shamaika" ]
```

EDIT: The `getMyUsers` function can also be coded in a more detailed way as follows:

```
function getMyUsers2() {

    let usersWithH = [];

    for (let user of users) {
        let userChars = user.split("");
        if (userChars[1] == "h") {
            usersWithH.push(user);
        }
    }

    return usersWithH;
}

console.log(getMyUsers2()); // prints [ "Sherry", "Shamaika" ]
```